# to pass the html combobox value to php in same file without submit

Tags: php, html, combobox

i want to change the combobox2 entry based on the selection in another combobox1..
i want to retrieve the entries of combobox2 from database , i need to do this in php.
For this i need to pass the selected value in combobox1 to the php as php variable. tried a lot... but not yet got the output.
Here is my code

```
Degree Type<select id="Select3" name="deg">
            <option value="UG">UG</option>
             <option value="PG">PG</option>
        </select>
Department Name<?php 

        $host="localhost" ; 
    $mysql_db="db" ; 
    $mysql_u="root" ; 
    $mysql_p="" ; 
    mysql_connect( "$host", "$mysql_u", "$mysql_p"); 
    mysql_select_db( "$mysql_db"); 
    $sel="select Dept_Name from dept_mast where Deg_Type='???' "; 

    $val=mysql_query($sel);
    $selectbox='<select name=\'userst\'>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($val)) {
$selectbox.='<option value=\"' . $row['Dept_Name'] . '\">' . $row['Dept_Name'] .  '</option>';
}
$selectbox.='</select>';
echo $selectbox;
        ?>
```

how can i pass the selected value in degree type combobox in the place of `???`

Help Me!
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use a POST, then you have to do it with ajax

Comment: You can not do it directly from server. Selection in the combo box is done on client's browser so you need to post your selection to server and fill your combobox2 entry from server response. Either do it with ajax or synchronized server request.

Comment: @Michal-sk 웃 can you show an eg code? i m a complete newbie in this topic...

Comment: No. But you can use google to find very much examples on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    js:
    ----

    function get_fields() { 

       var cource = $("#cource option:selected").val();

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'get_fields.php?cource='+cource,
             //Specify the datatype of response if necessary
             data: $("#form_id").serialize(),
             success: function(data){
                    $("span#column").html(data);
             }
        });

    }


    form.html
    ---------


    // Select the cource

    <select name="cource" id="cource"  onchange="get_fields()">
        <option value="Select" >Select</option>
        <option value="PG" >PG</option>
        <option value="UG" >UG</option>
    </select>

    <span id="column">
        <select name="department" id="department">
            <option value="Select" >Select</option> 
        </select>
    </span>


    get_fields.php
    ---------------

    <?php 

      $select = "select * from department where cource_code = '$_REQUEST['cource']' ";
      $department = mysql_query($select);

     ?>

     <select  name="department" id="department"  >
       <option value="select">Select</option>
        <?php
        if($department){
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($department)) {  ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['code'] ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($row['department_name']) ;?></option>
          <?php  }
        }
        ?>  
     </select>



Try this..Now you can filter with out submit using this code...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get values without refreshing the whole page, then you need to use ajax. In this example, its jQuery's `$.ajax`. (Simple same page ajax)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['get_values'])) {
    $data = array();
    $selected = $_POST['value'];
    $host = "localhost";
    $mysql_db = "db";
    $mysql_u = "root";
    $mysql_p = "";
    $con = new mysqli($host, $mysql_u, $mysql_p, $mysql_db);
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT Dept_Name FROM dept_mast WHERE Deg_Type = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $selected);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    // return value as json
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
}

?>

<select id="Select3" name="deg">
    <option value="UG">UG</option>
    <option value="PG">PG</option>
</select>
<div id="second_select"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Select3').on('change', function(){
    // when user selects a value
        var selected = $(this).val(); // get the value
            // request to server
        $.ajax({
            url: document.URL, // same page process
            type: 'POST',
            data: {get_values: true, value: selected},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(response) {
                        // get the response of the server, and put it inside a new select box
                $('#second_select').html('<select name="userst"></select>');
                var options = '';
                $.each(response, function(index, element){
                    options += '<option value="'+element.Dept_Name+'">'+element.Dept_Name+'</option>';
                });
                $('select[name="userst"]').html(options);
            }
        });
    });


});
</script>
```

> Sidenote: It's not discouraged, AVOID! Using mysql_* functions, use the NEWER and IMPROVED version **`MYSLQI`** or PDO

Comment: i am a newbie to AJAX.. i analysed your answer it was clear but i am having a doubt what is `?` in your code at select query will you please explain that

Comment: needed your guidance and reply

Comment: @user3763227 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) this will explain it better